# How to sum a bunch of variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

Suppose we have 1000 variables:

```
a_1 = 4
a_2 = 6
.
.
.
a_1000 = 76
```

What would be the best/most efficient way to sum these variables? Would something like the below work:

```
  sum_all_list = []
    for i in range(1001):
        sum_all_list.append(globals()['a_{}'.format(i)])
  sum_all = sum(sum_all_list)
```

Comment: Easiest way is to **not have** a thousand similar variables. Have them in one list instead.

Comment: @khelwood: Let's assume they are already defined like that?

Comment: Then edit the code that defined them like that and fix it. Having them in separate variables is a terrible programming decision.

Comment: "Would something like the below work?" Have you tried it? Did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dir()` and `eval()` functions:

```
a_1 = 4
a_2 = 6
a_3 = 5
a_4 = 2
a_8 = 5
a_1859 = 20
varList = dir()
sum = 0
for var in varList:
  if "a_" in var:
    sum += eval(var)

print(sum)
```

Resulting output:

```
42
```

Answer (score 4):

I would instead search for them inside globals and then simply add them up:

```py
res = 0
for vn,vv in globals().items():
    if vn[:2] == 'a_':
        res += vv
```

Answer (score 2):

The above example will work, but you can sum variables straight away like this:

```
sum = 0
for _ in range(1001):
  sum += globals()['a_{}'.format(i)]
```

However, it's better to store all the values in one list.

```
bunch_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What if there are 1005 variables?

Comment: @S3DEV this whole question is absurd, but you can do what Brandt suggested in his answer

Comment: Ah yes, we certainly agree.  I was simply pointing out that this solution is not robust.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a list?
If you are given a large number of variables containing different numbers. I'd copy it all to a text file. And use:
[This](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/).
and then turn it into a list.